# Using a service activator to change a message in Spring Integration, but getting a No Method Found error when the method definitely exists

Tags: java, json, service, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I'm new to Spring Integration and RabbitMQ and am stuck. I'm trying to write a program using spring integration that sends a message to one queue, then checks to see if the name property of the message exists in a hashmap: if it does exist, a "1" is added to the message, and if it doesn't "-1" is added. The message with the added number is then supposed to be sent to another queue.

Currently, the message is getting from the first queue to the second queue, but nothing is being added on because I'm getting a failed to transform message error.

I'm using a class called MessageCreator to make the original message and MessageImprover to add to the message.

Code:

```
package SpringMessaging;

public class MessageCreator {

private String messageJson;
private String name;
private int age;
public int count = 0;

 public String getName(){
 return name;
 }

 public int getAge(){
 return age;
  }

public void add(String name, int age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
   messageJson = "{" +
            "\"name\": \"" + name + "\"" +
            ", \"age\": " + age + ", \"count\": " + count +
            '}';
}

public String getJson() {
return messageJson;
    }
}


package SpringMessaging;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MessageImprover {
    private String jsonMessage;


public MessageCreator improve (MessageCreator creator) {
    MessageCreator changed = new MessageCreator();
    changed.add(creator.getName(), creator.getAge());
     HashMap<String, Integer> table = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            table.put("Icelantic", 8);
            table.put("Nordica", 9);
            table.put("Atomic", 10);
            table.put("Volkl", 11);
            table.put("Marker", 12);
        if(table.containsKey(creator.getName())==true){
            changed.count = 1;
      } else {
            changed.count = -1;
    }

     return changed;
    }
}
```

Here is the Main method:

```
public class Main {

public static void create(ApplicationContext context) {
    Sender sender = (Sender) context.getBean("Sender");     
    MessageCreator creator = new MessageCreator();
         creator.add("Icelantic", 25);
         sender.sendMessage(creator);

}            
public static void main(String[] args) {   
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/SpringMessaging/ReceivingConfig.xml");
  create(context);
    }
}
```

Here are my xml config files:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp" 
   xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd"> 

   <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="bigdata-rdp" username="myuser" password="mypass" />
   <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
   <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
   <rabbit:queue name="first" auto-delete="false" durable="true" />
   <rabbit:queue name="second" auto-delete="false" durable="true" />

   <rabbit:fanout-exchange name="first-exchange" auto-delete="true" durable="true">
  <rabbit:bindings>
     <rabbit:binding queue="first" />
  </rabbit:bindings>
   </rabbit:fanout-exchange>

  <int:channel id="senderChannel">    
    </int:channel>

  <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="senderChannel" exchange-name="first-exchange"  amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />

   <int-amqp:outbound-gateway id="outbound" request-channel="senderChannel"  exchange-name="first-exchange" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />

   <int:gateway id="Sender" service-interface="SpringMessaging.Sender" default-request-channel="senderChannel">
       <int:method name="sendMessage" />
    </int:gateway>

  <int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="100"/>

</beans>
```

That config is just for sending to the first queue, and here is the other config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp" 
   xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:/SpringMessaging/SendingConfig.xml" />

   <rabbit:fanout-exchange name="second-exchange" auto-delete="true" durable="true">
      <rabbit:bindings>
         <rabbit:binding queue="second" />
      </rabbit:bindings>
   </rabbit:fanout-exchange>

    <int:channel id="realreceiver">
        <int:queue />
     </int:channel>

   <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="receiverChannel"  />
        <int:bridge input-channel="receiverChannel" output-channel="realreceiver" />

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="realreceiver" exchange-name="second-exchange"  amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />

   <int-amqp:inbound-gateway id="inbound" request-channel="receiverChannel"  amqp-template="amqpTemplate" queue-names="first, second" connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge-mode="AUTO"  />

   <int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="senderChannel" output-channel="receiverChannel" />

   <int:chain input-channel="receiverChannel">
      <int:json-to-object-transformer type="SpringMessaging.MessageCreator" />
        <int:service-activator method="improve">
            <bean class="SpringMessaging.MessageImprover" />
         </int:service-activator>
      <int:object-to-json-transformer content-type="text/json" />
   </int:chain>

   <int:service-activator input-channel="senderChannel" output-channel="receiverChannel" ref="MessageImprover" method = "improve" />

   <bean id="MessageImprover" class="SpringMessaging.MessageImprover" />
    <bean id="MessageCreator" class="SpringMessaging.MessageCreator" />

</beans>
```

The "improve" method is defined in the MessageImprover but it's not being recognized.

StackTrace:

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:915)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:825)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message
>       at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:44)
>       at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:236)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
>       at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:459)
>       at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:426)
>       at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway.access$1100(AmqpInboundGateway.java:64)
>       at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway$Listener.doOnMessage(AmqpInboundGateway.java:307)
>       at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundGateway.java:259)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822)
>       ... 10 more
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
>    at [Source: (byte[])""; line: 1, column: 0]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:58)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4089)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3996)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3109)
>       at org.springframework.integration.support.json.Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.fromJson(Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.integration.support.json.Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.fromJson(Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.java:52)
>       at org.springframework.integration.support.json.AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.fromJson(AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.integration.json.JsonToObjectTransformer.doTransform(JsonToObjectTransformer.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:33)
>       ... 30 more

Comment: Could you share the whole stack trace?

Comment: thanks. have you made sure the Spring dependencies you're using are compatible versions? the framework seems to be trying to access an exception constructor that does not exist, and that is probably obscuring the root cause.

Comment: Not related, but you shouldn't use a queue channel as the output channel of the rabbit adapter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change that right now.

Comment: @LucasRoss how can I check if they're compatible? I'm very new to all this.

Comment: look at the versions. if you're using maven they'll be in the pom.xml. you can see on the spring-amqp docs for the current release version, for instance, that Spring 4.3.x is recommended. http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_introduction.html#compatibility

Comment: I'm using the latest version of everything.

Comment: shoot... well, if you share your project on a public repo, i wouldn't mind pulling it down and taking a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

??

`public String improve (MessageCreator creator)`

`improve()` takes an object of type `MessageCreator` which means the message payload must be a `MessageCreator` whereas it looks like your messages are just the JSON part of the creator `sender.sendMessage(creator.getJson());`

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the answer! I just changed it to send the MessageCreator object instead of the JSON part, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Something very strange is going on; a service-activator should never try to invoke a constructor `<init>`; turn on DEBUG logging and follow the message flow to see if it gives you any clues.

Comment: Ok, I'll post that soon. Is it possible that the "improve" method returning a string and I'm now sending an object could be causing a problem?

Comment: >`<int:json-to-object-transformer type="SpringMessaging.MessageImprover" />` doesn't make sense to me - that class contains logic, not data - shouldn't that be `MessageCreator`? The type is a hint to Jackson to tell it what class to transform the json to.

Comment: Thanks!! I changed that and am now getting a Message failed to transform error. I updated the code and the stacktrace. So now I guess something is wrong with the chain?

Comment: You should use a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` in the template and inbound channel adapters. The default converter can only handle String, byte[] and java `Serializable` objects; . You then won't need the transformer; the converter will convert the inbound message. In the upcoming 2.0 release the default converter will throw an exception for payloads it can't handle; in older versions, and empty `byte[]` was sent - hence your error.

Comment: Hi Gary, so I've figured out something interesting. The reason in the first place that the strange error was occurring was because the "improve" method takes a parameter. I removed the parameter and the error disappeared. However, without that parameter, I'm not sure how to update the original message to change the "count" property.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without having the code. If you can post a stripped-down app somewhere that reproduces the issue, someone could take a look. I will be out of action for the next couple of weeks, though.

Comment: Ok, I'll put it up on github soon if I can't resolve the issue myself. Thanks!